# How Do I return larger size from graph "picture"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having a hard time figuring this out, information out there seems to be old and graph explorer is not showing intelisense for picture I don't know why...

my last approach was this: `me?fields=cover,name,id,picture{url,width}` which returns only the information I can't force it to return a larger size

any tips are welcome thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/me?fields=picture.type(large)
```

...or if you need specific sizes or aspect ratios:

```
/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`me?fields=cover,name,id,picture.width(700)`